# How can I provide support for a non-core field type?

Tags: 8, migrations

What is the necessary implementation to add support for a field type so that it is picked up by the core migrate_drupal upgrade process?

For example, the Weight module. It provides a simple field that holds a number, but the core migrate drupal module can't seem to map the source to the destination automagically like it can for most of my other fields.

Does this require placing plugin yaml files in modulename/migration_templates?